# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un email en Jenkins según si existen ficheros o no?

Tags: jenkins

En mi trabajo tengo que hacer una serie de validaciones diarias. Sus resultados son importantes y en muchos casos no devuelven información. Ahora bien, si la devuelven, genero unos ficheros automáticamente que se envían a distintas personas.

Todo esto lo tengo configurado con una serie de scripts de Python que lanzo desde Jenkins. El script de Python es sencillito y dependiendo de su resultado creará un fichero o no. Resumiéndolo mucho, un job aleatorio está definido así:

#### Build → Execute shell

```
python -m mis_scripts.informe_blabla
```

Y las acciones de post-build consisten en una notificación de email editable de este forma:

#### Post-build actions → Editable email notification

#### → Success:

- recipient list: `email1, email2, ...`
- (...)
- attachments: `ficheros_*.xlsx`

Como veis, la clave está en la última línea: `ficheros_*.xlsx` utiliza [@includes of Ant fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html), por lo que incorpora todos los ficheros que coinciden con este patrón. Puede haber uno, muchos ("ficheros_1.xlsx", "ficheros_holaquétal.xlsx"...) o ninguno. Ese último caso es el que no me gusta: si no se creó ningún fichero, el email se envía igualmente pero sin ningún adjunto.

Lo que querría es que este email solamente se enviara si existe al menos un fichero que coincide con este patrón.

Lo más que he conseguido es añadir una condición en la parte de "Build → Execute shell":

```
if [ -n "$(find . -name '*ficheros_*.xlsx' | head -n 1)" ]; then
  exit 0   # hay ficheros, ¡ok!
else
  exit 1   # no hay ficheros
fi
```

De este modo, marcas un estado de salida para el script y luego lo recoges con → Sucess o → Failure. Es decir, si hay ficheros lo marcas como éxito y si no los hay, como fallo.

Sin embargo, no deja de ser teóricamente incorrecto porque marco como fallado un build que sí fue exitoso, pero que no dio pie a enviar un email. Es decir, quiero dejar los estados "Success" y "Failure" limpios y centrados en la ejecución, no en la lógica del script.

Probé con el plugin [Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) pero solamente me permite ejecutar cosas, no definir qué "post-build action" ejecutar.

La pregunta es:
**¿Existe alguna forma de enviar un email con ficheros adjuntos configurables si se cumple una condición determinada?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Lo solucioné! Instalando el plugin [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) puedes definir pasos a realizar durante el "build".

En este caso, creé un paso de "build" a continuación del "Execute shell" que ejecuta el script de Python.

Este paso nuevo revisa si hay ficheros que coinciden con el patrón "ficheros_*.xlsx". Si lo hay, lanza otro job "envio_email_notificacion", que simplemente hace el envío:

#### Build → Conditional step (single)

- Run? Files match

  - Includes: `ficheros_*.xlsx`
- Builder: Trigger/call builds on other projects

  - Build Triggers:

    - Projects to build: "envio_email_notificacion"

Es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]